How should i style the content using Tailwind CSS?
I'm trying to style my header item container and inside that i have a home icon and i'm pulling that icon from the header page and everything is working like if i try to give header or p tag but when i'm styling the icon or any p tag etc. i'm not getting any results on the webpage i think it must be tailwind css problem but i'm not able to figure out what is it.
This is the Header.js
import {
    BadgeCheckIcon,
    CollectionIcon,
    HomeIcon,
    LightningBoltIcon,
    SearchIcon,
    UserIcon,
} from "@heroicons/react/24/outline";
import Image from "next/image";
import HeaderItem from "./HeaderItem";

function Header() {
  return (
    <header className="">
        <div>
            {/* This is for icons that i'm using on the components section */}
            <HeaderItem title ='HOME' Icon = {HomeIcon}/>
        </div>
        {/* This is the logo image we are going to add in header component */}
        <Image
            className="object-contain"
            src='/images/hulu.png' 
            width={200} 
            height={100}
        />
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header

and this is HeaderItem.js

function HeaderItem({ Icon, title }) {
  return (
    <div>
        <Icon className='h-8 mb-1'/>
        <p className="opacity-0 hover:opacity-100 tracking-widest">{title}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HeaderItem;

This is my tailwind.config.js file
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        background: "var(--background)",
        foreground: "var(--foreground)",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};

you can see ii was styling using tailwind but it is not reflecting on my webpage.


What version of NextJS are you on? Do you have Tailwind installed? Did you restart your dev server after you installed Tailwind? Are there any errors in the Terminal/console?

I'm using 14.2.13 version of NextJs and yes i installed tailwind and i have tailwind.config.js file in my project and there are no errors in my terminal.
tailwind base;
tailwind components;
tailwind utilities;
layer base {
body {
apply bg-[#06202A] text-gray-300
}
}
this is my global.css file (i have the @ symbols in the code as well)

Thanks for the responses. Do ANY Tailwind-styled components show styling? If not, I'd look at your tailwind.config and make sure you're looking for js extension and not only typescript.

no not even one tailwind styling component is working
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} /
module.exports = {
content: [
"./src/pages/**/.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
"./src/components//*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
"./src/app//*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
],
theme: {
extend: {
colors: {
background: "var(--background)",
foreground: "var(--foreground)",
},
},
},
plugins: [],
};
this is my tailwind.config.js file

Where is your Header.js located? I'm trying to see if the relative location of your Header.js matches the content pattern on your tailwind config.

My Header.js is located in components folder and index.js in pages folder and HeaderItem.js that conains the Icon is also is in components folder. Do we get an option to post an image here in the comments so that i can show you the entire project structure.

@ram shinde Please add your tailwind.config file code in the above question (not in comments) by editing it. Are you using app or pages router ?

@Beast80K i added my tailwind code in my question and i'm using page router because when i was creating the project on warp there was a question are you going to use app router then i selected "No" is that causing a problem ?

@ram shinde Tailwind CSS is not applying to anything, like not even font-bold text-5xl like nothing ??

@Beast80K No it is not changing for anything and i also uploaded a screenshot of my localhost page you can see the icon is not changing the size even when i change the styling.

You should pass the Icon prop to HeaderItem as a JSX :
...
<HeaderItem title ='HOME' Icon ={<HomeIcon className='h-8 mb-1'/>}/>
...

and you can use the passed prop inside the HeaderItem like this
function HeaderItem({ Icon, title }) {
  return (
    <div>
        {Icon}
        <p className="opacity-0 hover:opacity-100 tracking-widest">{title}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

the HomeIcon itself is just a reference but <HomeIcon/> is the instance of it.
